# QGIS Azimuth and Distance Plugin Right/Left Curve Input

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, distance, azimuth, curved

I'm having a problem with left/right curve of radius rr and distance dd entry for the Azimuth & Distance Plugin. I've only used the plug in for straight lines and it has performed fine. I now have a set deed boundary information I'm trying to plot that includes arcs/curves right & left. At the far right is the information direct from the deed in an Excel spreadsheet. I manually input that data to the plug-in as seen in the middle screen. What I'm getting is the funky line shown on the QGIS screen at the left in (dashed violet).

Could someone tell me what I'm inputting incorrectly in the plug-in table from the spreadsheet?

I believe its to do with the curve information but I'm an electrical engineer and not a civil engineer so I don't have the surveyor skills needed. I've been trying for several hours changing things, searching online for help and all I seem to do is make funky lines - no land parcels. I was trying to find online an example where someone had put in similar curve information for this plug-in I could use as an example and have been unsuccessful finding such. Would be nice in the plug-in to provide a simple example as it took me a while to figure out how to do a simple square of land! Option settings are Boundary-Bearing-Feet-Degree, North is default.

[image: My Data for entering a land plot with curves]